# Store and Scrape Over Time

Tags: python, sqlite, beautifulsoup

I'm brand new here and brand new to Python and programming in general. I wrote a simple script today that I'm pretty proud of as a new beginner. I used BS4 and Requests to scrape some data from a website. I put all of the data in dictionaries inside a list. The same key/value pairs exist for every list item. For simplicity, I'm left with something like this:

```
[{'country': 'us', 'state':'new york', 'people':50},{'country':'us', 'state':'california','people':30']}
```

Like I said, pretty simple, but then I can turn it into a Pandas dataframe and everything is organized with a few hundred different dictionaries inside the list. My next step is to do run this scrape every hour for 5 hours--and the only thing that changes is the value of the 'people' key. All of the sudden I'm not sure a list of lists of dictionaries (did I say that right?!) is a great idea. Plus, I really only need to get the updated values of 'people' from the webpage. Is this something I can realistically do with built in Python lists and dictionaries? I don't know much about databases, but I'm thinking that maybe SQLite might be good to use. I really only know about it in concept but haven't worked with it. Thoughts?

Ideally, after several scrapes, I would have easy access to the data to say, see 'people' in 'new york' over time. Or find at what time 'california' had the highest number of people. And then I could plot the data in 1000 different ways! I'd love any guidance or direction here. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Python class, like this:

```
class StateStats:
    def __init__(self, country, state, people):
        self.country = country
        self.state = state
        self.people = people

    def update():
        # Do whatever your update script is here
        # Except, update the value self.people when it changes
        # Like this: self.people = newPeopleValueAsAVariable
```

And then create instances of it like this:

```
# For each country you have scraped, make a new instance of this class
# This assumes that the list you gathered is stored in a variable named my_list
state_stats_list = []
for dictionary in my_list:
    state_stats_list.append(
        StateStats(
            dictionary['country'], 
            dictionary['state'], 
            dictionary['people']
        )
    )

# Or, instead, you can just create the class instances 
# when you scrape the webpage, instead of creating a 
# list and then creating another list of classes from that list
```

You could also use a database like SQLite, but I think this will be fine for your purpose. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up creating a second list as my “working” list. I used a time.sleep() function inside a for loop with the help of a counter to have it run and append its own dictionary to the main dict.